# How can I merge my Unity Scene using Unity Smart Merge?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, merge, scene

I am trying to merge a Unity scene my partner and I have been working on, using Smart Merge. My other assets and prefabs resolved the conflicts with Smart Merge just fine; however, one scene isn't merging at all.

**In my .git/config file I added**

```
[merge]
tool = unityyamlmerge
[mergetool "unityyamlmerge"]
trustExitCode = false
cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\Tools\\UnityYAMLMerge.exe' merge -p "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$LOCAL" "$MERGED"
```

**I've also included a .gitattributes file containing**

```
*.unity binary
*.prefab binary
*.asset binary
```

**I've set my asset serilialization to 'Force Text' and Version Control to 'Visible Meta Files.'**

Our prefabs and other assets merged fine, but one of our scenes doesn't merge at all.

When running the `git mergetool` command in the terminal, it displays the conflicts for this specified scene, but then returns this at the end:

```
Left  563852304.Light.m_Color.r add as 0.8962264
Right 563852304.Light.m_Color.r add as 0.9433962
Left  610301896.GameObject.m_IsActive add as 0
Right 610301896.GameObject.m_IsActive add as 1
Left  610301898.Transform.m_LocalPosition.x add as -13.07
Right 610301898.Transform.m_LocalPosition.x add as -14.31
Left  610301898.Transform.m_LocalPosition.y add as 2.6
Right 610301898.Transform.m_LocalPosition.y add as 2.14
Left  610301898.Transform.m_RootOrder add as 8
Right 610301898.Transform.m_RootOrder add as 7
Left  869912137.Transform.m_LocalPosition.x add as -7.36
Right 869912137.Transform.m_LocalPosition.x add as -7.333
Left  869912137.Transform.m_LocalScale.x add as 4
Right 869912137.Transform.m_LocalScale.x add as 4.0070143
Conflict handling:
Xmas-Prototype-01/Assets/_Scenes/InitScene.unity seems unchanged.
Was the merge successful [y/n]?
```

There's more conflict, but too much to list.

This is the only file that hasn't merged with my local branch. Is there a way I can get this one scene to merge?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this isn't much of an answer.
The typical best practice when working with scenes and git, is to only have one person working on a scene at a time. We have been using a "scene hat".

What we've been doing (indie studio) is to [additively load multiple scenes](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html), so the level designer(s) have one scene without functionality to work on, and programmers (who don't need a lot of time with a scene) have a "bootstrap" scene, which contains game functionality.

Comment: By "scene hat" do you mean the description in the second paragraph (a good strategy), or is that something else?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should ensure yamlmergetool can handle .unity, .prefabs, and anything else as plain text (not binary) by adding this in your [.gitattributes](https://gist.github.com/FullStackForger/fe2b3da81e60337757fe82d74ebf7d7a)

```
*.unity merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.prefab merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
```

One of the things that annoys me about YAML is how it seems there’s no sense to where text is added through edits in the scene. If you add a GameObject to the very bottom of the scene list it appears in a random place in the source of the YAML. If you move it, rather than move the source code, it changes a property called `m_RootOrder` to reflect the zero index order of the root. When the yamlmergetool starts it quickly gets confused because source code editors are dealing with lines numbers + blocks of code that look the same. As @thefragen has pointed out, a good way to deal with this is to have your collaborators work in separate scenes to avoid potential merge issues.