# Filter confidential information on git bare repo

Tags: git, dotfiles

I'm using a bare repository for tracking my dotfiles and trying to filter the passwords and API keys from some of the files.

**.gitattributes**

```
 some-dotfile filter=remove-pass
```

**.git/config**

```
 [filter "remove-pass"]
 clean = "sed -e 's/^password=.*/#password=TODO/'"
```

This works on default repositories but not in a bare.

Comment: A bare repo doesn't have the working tree so it doesn't work with files, it only works with Git object database and references. No commits from the (absent) working tree, no diff with working tree, no filters.

Comment: Thanks, @phd ! I guess I would do a file to store the keys and retrieve them where needed then!

Comment: That might [work with Git 2.43](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73095814/6309) though, since Git now can read `.gitattributes` from a bare repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clean` command is called upon checkin. By default, a bare repository does not have a work tree, and we cannot run `git commit` in it. So, the `clean` command in a bare repository is not expected to be invoked in most cases. Commands like `git push` and `git fetch` do not invoke the `clean` command.

There is a case in which the `clean` command configured in a bare repository can work. But it's tricky and rare.

```
git init --bare /home/me/foo
# edit /home/me/foo/config
[filter "remove-pass"]
     clean = "sed -e 's/^password=.*/#password=TODO/'"

# create a non-bare repository
git init /home/me/bar
cd /home/me/bar
touch some-dotfile
echo 'some-dotfile filter=remove-pass' > .gitattributes

# use the work tree of the non-bare repository and the gitdir of the bare repository
git --git-dir=/home/me/foo --work-tree=/home/me/bar add .
git --git-dir=/home/me/foo --work-tree=/home/me/bar commit -m'init'

echo 'password=helloworld' > some-dotfile
git --git-dir=/home/me/foo --work-tree=/home/me/bar add .
git --git-dir=/home/me/foo --work-tree=/home/me/bar commit -m'test clean command'
```

The 2 new commits are stored in `/home/me/foo` instead of `/home/me/bar/.git` as we specify `--git-dir`. Now check the content of the committed `some-dotfile`,

```
git clone /home/me/foo -- /home/me/myfoo
cat /home/me/myfoo/some-dotfile
```

The `cat` command prints `#password=TODO` so we know the `clean` command takes effect. However, we would unlikely use a bare repository like this.